# How can I use JavaScript conditional for Mac based browsers?

Tags: macos, safari

I'd like to use special css rules for Firefox, Chrome and Safari under Mac OS, but I don't know how to write the conditional in the page's header. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here -> [Browser detect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

edit:

[Different CSS depending on OS (Mac or PC)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/dyncss.htm)

Comment: yes I saw that page, but how to write to conditional? if browser is firefox on mac then call special css file? if browser is safari on mac then call special css file? if browser is chrome on mac then call special css file? I can write conditionals in js, but not for browser related things...

Comment: thanks but i'm afraid that's not really what i'm looking for :(

Comment: This worked for me, thumbs up!